# Flutter: Implement Material Search bar to search data from a server async

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to implement material search in my flutter app using the [SearchDelegate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html) class.

I have implemented this with a local list of items. How can I use this to get list of items from a REST API asynchronously. I already have an API which gives the list of items for a given string. I just need to know how to do it asynchronously using the [SearchDelegate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html) class in Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), have a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo&vl=en)